# Getting a count from a nested query with a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an SQL statement in which I want to group all the data from a row into either one of two groups and then get a count on those and depending on which group it falls under.

```
SELECT vehicle "type", count(*) "count"
FROM(
      SELECT
        CASE
          WHEN auto_type LIKE 'chevy' THEN 'domestic'
          WHEN auto_type LIKE 'ford'  THEN 'domestic'
          ELSE 'foreign'
         END as "vehicle"
       FROM table_name
     )
 GROUP BY vehicle
```

My end goal it to have it display a table with the two types as type and a count of each.  The nested statement works by itself as does the one where I am just getting the count.  It's when I put the two together is when I get the issue.  It gives me an ORA-00904: "vehicle": invalid identifier  Error.

Comment: Did you try switching references to `"vehicle"` ?   Oracle syntax is confusing to me, seems like it wants double quotes usually but not always.

Comment: Doesn't oracle support "group by 1" syntax? Might be a silly way of addressing, but change your group by from group by vehicle to group by 1...oracle should figure out the column name on it's own

Comment: I almost feel silly for asking the question now but after reading the comment from @GoatCO I tried adding double quotes around vehicle in the select and group by and it worked.  I also tried group by 1 by it still didn't like that.

Comment: Most people here tend to use multiple database types (I like to call it database agnostic)...Oracle has some special handling on quoting that the other languages don't use as much and it results in some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly change the query removing the quotes while using vehicle as a column to the below 
since this [online test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33245) is working fine

```
SELECT vehicle "type", count(*) "count"
FROM(
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN auto_type LIKE 'chevy' THEN 'domestic'
      WHEN auto_type LIKE 'ford'  THEN 'domestic'
      ELSE 'foreign'
     END as vehicle
   FROM table_name
 )
GROUP BY vehicle
```

Comment: I have found that I can either remove the quotes from vehicle or add quotes to each instance of it in the query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN auto_type IN ('ford','chevy') THEN 1 end) as domestic_cnt, 
       sum(CASE WHEN auto_type NOT IN ('ford','chevy') THEN 1 end) as foreign_cnt
FROM table_name
```